# How to format axis date_time label in `ggplot2`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, axis-labels

I am trying to plot a time series, and notice that the date_time label for the x-axis is not formatting as expected.

```
library(ggplot2)
My_df = data.frame(My_datetime = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2019-05-21 8:00:00"), 
                                     to = as.POSIXct("2019-05-22 23:00:00"), 
                                     by = "10 min"),
                   My_data = sin(1:235))

ggplot(data = My_df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = My_datetime, y = My_data)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = c(as.POSIXct("2019-05-21 9:00:00"), 
                              as.POSIXct("2019-05-21 15:00:00"), 
                              as.POSIXct("2019-05-22 21:00:00")), 
                   labels=scales::date_format("%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

I'd like to show only three x-axis labels: `05-21 09:00`, `05-21 15:00`, and `05-22 21:00`. However, it now shows as `05-21 15:00`, `05-21 21:00`, and `05-23 03:00`. I wonder how to fix this? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time zones are messing with your outputs! For safety, use `lubridate::as_datetime`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
My_df = data.frame(My_datetime = seq(from = lubridate::as_datetime("2019-05-21 8:00:00"), 
                                     to = lubridate::as_datetime("2019-05-22 23:00:00"), 
                                     by = "10 min"),
                   My_data = sin(1:235))

ggplot(data = My_df) +
  geom_line(aes(x = My_datetime, y = My_data)) + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = c(lubridate::as_datetime("2019-05-21 9:00:00"), 
                              lubridate::as_datetime("2019-05-21 15:00:00"), 
                              lubridate::as_datetime("2019-05-22 21:00:00")), 
                   labels=scales::date_format("%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

[image]

Comment: Made a slight edit there - matching up dates from dataframe to ggplot needs them both in the same time zone. Ggplot translates the breaks to your system time zone. In your graph they're plotted in the right place but adjusted for local time. `lubridate::as_datetime` will at least keep it consistent wherever you run your code and be semi-agnostic to locale.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. In my code, I do not assign any time zone when I create `My_df` and then plot. I wonder how R can mess up with the date time? What do you mean by `In your graph they're plotted in the right place but adjusted for local time.`? Thanks.